# Beginner trying to make a line ggplot with categorical X axis and customising color settings

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to

(1) create a line ggplot using some variables as factors and
(2) set a specific color and a thicker line width for one of the color variable groups (group "0" in ID1).

For my first problem I keep getting the error message:

> "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"

and for the second, I have no idea where to begin.

My data looks like this:

```
ID1 ID2 Q   V
503 503-2879    1   6.9
503 503-2879    2   14.21
503 503-2879    3   20.76
503 503-2879    6   36.64
503 503-2879    12  56.39
503 503-2879    20  68.87
503 503-2879    30  74.85
503 503-2879    40  76.87
504 504-2880    1   24.23
504 504-2880    2   34.41
504 504-2880    3   42.74
504 504-2880    6   59.7
504 504-2880    12  74.1
504 504-2880    20  79.04
504 504-2880    30  80.12
504 504-2880    40  80.27
755 755-3021    1   15.2
755 755-3021    2   19.5
755 755-3021    3   23.63
755 755-3021    6   35.02
755 755-3021    12  53.86
755 755-3021    20  72.57
755 755-3021    30  88.56
755 755-3021    40  99.01
0   N   1   1.526709
0   N   2   3.053418
0   N   3   4.580127
0   N   6   9.226632
0   N   12  18.453264
0   N   20  30.733313
0   N   30  46.06678
0   N   40  61.47
```

My initial code produced a graph that is very close to what I want  (without adding the color and line width settings for the "0" color group) but the X axis is continuous when in fact this variable is categorical.

Initial code:

```
GPlot <- ggplot(VbyQG, aes(x = Q, y = V, color = ID1)) +
           geom_path() + 
           theme_bw() + 
           theme(legend.position = 'none') + 
           theme_classic() + 
           theme(legend.position = 'none') + 
           expand_limits(y = 210)
GPlot
```

I would like the X axis to show the correct breaks and labels (1, 2, 3, 6, 12, 20, 30, 40) of the "Q" variable.

I have tried changing the "Q" variable into a factor using str() and also factor() within the ggplot aes() but while either of these changes take care of the error message and result in the X axis displaying the correct breaks and labels, they also make all the data disappear.

How can I make the data appear again? Also, what sort of coding do I need to add to set a specific color and a thicker line width for one of the color variable groups (group "0" in ID1)?
I have searched for solutions for my second problem but the solutions I have found are beyond my beginner coding skills. Many thanks again for the help!

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for but does this work for you? `GPlot <- ggplot(df, aes(x = as.factor(Q), y = V, color = as.factor(ID1), group=as.factor(ID1))) +
  geom_path() + 
  theme_classic() + 
  expand_limits(y = 210)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, this should work. The idea is to convert Q to a character, and then make it an ordered factor using fct_reorder from the `forcats` package included in `tidyverse`. (I am assuming Q is numeric in your source.)

```
library(tidyverse)  

df2 <- df %>% 
  # Takes Q, assumed numeric, saves as character, then converts to ordered factor
  mutate(Q = as.character(Q) %>% fct_reorder(Q))

GPlot <- ggplot(df2, aes(x= Q, y = V, color = ID1, group = ID1)) +
  geom_path() + 
  # Here's one way to highlight -- just draw on top with manual color & size
  # geom_path(data = df2 %>% filter(ID1 == 503),
  #           size = 2, color = "slateblue") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none') + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'none') + 
  expand_limits(y = 210)
GPlot
```

[image]

To highlight one series, the simplest thing might be to use the `gghightlight` package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gghighlight/vignettes/gghighlight.html

Or you could use a manual scale for color and thickness and make just that series highlighted. Or you could plot another layer on top with a manually defined color and thickness, but that won't automatically integrate with any legend labels.